# Django, many duplicated queries in my TabularInline

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

This is the part of my models.py:

```
class Media(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Topic(TimeStampedModel):
    medias = models.ManyToManyField(Media, through='TopicAndMedia')

class TopicAndMedia(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is the part of my admin.py:

```
class TopicAndMediaInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TopicAndMedia

class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TopicAndMediaInline, )
    ...
```

When I visit the TOPIC admin site, it's too slow. Here is the snapshot of the django-debug-tool

[image]

There are many duplicated time-cost queries like select * from 'topics_media'. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing typical problem with django QuerySets. You got this queries because when you access related object which is not prefetched beforehand you make additional DB hit.

Read more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

This should solve your problem

```
class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TopicAndMediaInline,)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(TopicAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.prefetch_related('medias')
        return qs
```

Comment: I added it, and also add the following in the TopicAndMediaInline                                                                                                     def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(TopicAndMediaInline, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.select_related('media')
        return qs                                                                                                           Still found many duplicated queries at the end.

Comment: Why would you add that?

Comment: Sorry for the bad format of former reply, let me say it again. After i add get_queryset(), still found many duplicated queries like "select * from 'topics_media' ", the amount of duplicated query is almost equal to the amount of medias it has

Comment: After i add raw_id_fields in TopicAndMediaInline, the duplicated queries disappered

Comment: It doesn't work in Django 2.0

Comment: @ramusus Does it give an error? It should work

Comment: no any errors, just bunch of queries in debug toolbar